# send json data without key

Tags: android, json

Hi all I want to send json data without key in android. I had sucessfully post json data with key val pair. But unable to post json data without key. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

For key val I used.

```
// 1. create HttpClient
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

// 2. make POST request to the given URL
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

String json = "";

// 3. build jsonObject
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.accumulate("mobNo",storedMobNo );



// 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
json = jsonObject.toString();



// 5. set json to StringEntity
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

// 6. set httpPost Entity
httpPost.setEntity(se);

// 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the
// content
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

// 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

// 9. receive response as inputStream
inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
```

In above code I had pass "mobNo" as key and storedMobNo as value. But Now I want to pass only storedMobNo not key. How to do this?

Comment: Send it as string or array

Comment: What does storedMobNo contain ?

Comment: storedMobNo  is a string

Comment: Ok Thanks guys after passing it as a String solves my issue. Thanks  Remees M Syde

Answer (score 0):

Try this type of json data:

```
{
    "column": ["mobno"],
    "data": [
        "123",
        "456",
        "789"
    ]
}
```